# mouseX/mouseY Actionscript function equivalent in Cocos2D

Tags: actionscript-3, cocos2d-iphone

This might be irritating simple. I am trying to convert some code from actionscript to cocos2d. I am quite new to actionscript and would like to know if there is a cocos2d function for mouseX/mouseY. If not, what would be the equivalent. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com) (which is based on cocos2d-iphone) you can use the [mouseLocation](http://learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/Kobold2D/html/interface_k_k_input.html#aa7b4a003c6bc31e036d38b2ebd2add51):

```
CGPoint mousePos = [KKInput sharedInput].mouseLocation;
```

KKInput captures the mouse location every time it receives an event. If mouse moved events are enabled, mouse location gives the accurate location of the mouse.

The alternative is to use the NSWindow method [mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream).